# Как менять блоки местами?

Tags: html, css

Нужно на моб. устройствах поменять блоки местами. Можно ли средствами bootstrap или юзать js?

Comment: Нужно чтобы блок, который находится снизу, был сверху.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. У вас адаптивная верстка и нужно, чтобы на мобильных устройствах, блок который был сверху переехал вниз, или же пользователь сам меняет положение блоков?

Comment: Можно и бутстрап, и js, и с помощью `flex`ов сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с помощью flexbox, изменяйте ширину окна браузера и увидите, как элементы будут меняться.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.one {
  order: 2;
  background: green;
}
.two {
  order: 1;
  background: purple;
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .one {
    order: 1;
  }
  .two {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two">Two</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap - [column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-md-push-6 col-sm-push-6">
      <h2>block 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-pull-6">
      <h2>block 1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```